# Nested ArrayList and manual database entry

Tags: android, sqlite, arraylist, cursor, android-recyclerview

I'm working on a RecyclerView in Android that looks like this:

**A**

A topic1

A topic2

A topic3

**B**

B topic1

B topic2

With the topics hidden until you tap on the parent letter.

I've got something that I think should be working, but now if I add rows to my database manually (which is by design), **additional rows aren't recognized**, even if I uninstall the app and load it back in. This is what I'm looking at:

```
final List<AToZList> aToZ = addTopics();
mAdapter = new AToZAdapter(getContext(), aToZ);
```

...

```
private List<AToZList> addTopics() {
        topics = new ArrayList<Topic>();
        List<AToZList> aToZ;
        AToZList A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z;
        A=B=C=D=E=F=G=H=I=J=K=L=M=N=O=P=Q=R=S=T=U=V=W=X=Y=Z = null;

        Cursor topicCursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT " + ExternalDbContract.QuoteEntry.TOPIC +
                " FROM " + ExternalDbContract.QuoteEntry.TABLE_NAME, null);

        try {
            for (topicCursor.moveToFirst(); !topicCursor.isAfterLast(); topicCursor.moveToNext()) {
                String firstLetter = topicCursor.getString(0).toUpperCase().substring(0, 1);

                switch (firstLetter) {
                    case "A":
                        if(A == null) {
                            A = new AToZList("A", getTopics(firstLetter));
                        }
                        break; //and so on for every letter
                }finally {
                    aToZ = Arrays.asList(A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z);
                }
    topicCursor.close();
    return aToZ;
```

...

```
private ArrayList<Topic> getTopics(String firstLetter) {
        Cursor topicCursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT " + ExternalDbContract.QuoteEntry.TOPIC +
                " FROM " + ExternalDbContract.QuoteEntry.TABLE_NAME, null);

        ArrayList<Topic> topicsByLetter = new ArrayList<Topic>();

        for(topicCursor.moveToFirst(); !topicCursor.isAfterLast(); topicCursor.moveToNext()) {
            if (topicCursor.getString(0).toUpperCase().substring(0, 1).equals(firstLetter)) {
                topicsByLetter.add(new Topic(topicCursor.getString(0)));
            }
        }
        topicCursor.close();
        return topicsByLetter;
    }
```

That's a lot of code.

I've added some logging to see what's actually getting passed through. I have 3 topic entries in the database, two that start with "A" and a third that starts with "B". The A's come through okay (there are two entries for that), and then for some reason it kicks out to the finally block, and ruins the Array because it only has one entry (as in, one "A" entry). `topicCursor.getCount()` tells me that there are only two entries, but there are three. CURSE YOU CURSOR!

If it would be helpful I've committed [where I'm at onto Github](https://github.com/jubby2000/Proclaim).

EDIT: I've edited the database itself to house completely different topic names and it continues to shows the previous topics. I've uninstalled the app from my test device so I'm really unsure where the data is coming from. But this definitely does seem database related.

Answer (score 0):

Aaaaaaand, problem solved.

Firstly, the database stuck around until I uninstalled **AND** rebooted. A simple uninstall for some reason wasn't enough.

The code I posted worked as expected. Just couldn't pass additional parameters that were null into the ArrayList (should add a check before I add any). Once I narrowed to only A and B, all errors were removed.

Here's the lesson: **If you're adding manual entries into a database, any updates will only be reflected once you uninstall the app, and then reboot.**